# Python inputs using list comprehensions

Tags: python-3.x

```py
n = int(input("Enter the size of the list "))
print("\n")
num_list = list(int(num) for num in input("Enter the list items separated by space ").strip().split())[:n]

print("User list: ", num_list)
```

can anyone explain this ......   i.e how it will work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The workflow is once you enter the size of the list value will be stored in variable 'n' and n printed in the interpreter.

```
n = int(input("Enter the size of the list ")) 
print("\n")
```

In the list comprehension  input().strip().split() is executed first i.e once you entered data is striped(removed leading and trailing spaces) and split data by space(default behavior) . then you entered data is iterated by iter variable (num) and num was converted into an integer as well as stored in num_list. Then finally you got num_list contains elements as int type.

```
num_list = list(int(num) for num in input("Enter the list items separated by space ").strip().split())
```

finally, list slicing as before n elements are returned into num_list.

```
num_list[:n]
```

Without list comprehension of how the above code works like......

```
num_list=[]
n = int(input("Enter the size of the list ")) 

print("\n")

for num in input("Enter the list items separated by space ").strip().split()):

    num_list.append(int(num))

    num_list=num_list[:n]
```

in one short in list comprehension every element in input is iterated by loop and typecasting it into int and before nth index elements are stored into num_list.